# How to get Visual Studio Community Edition 2019 working with Web Apps

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-runtime

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition on my Win10 Build 18362 Lenovo 550S System running Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 HTML 18.18362 and I can compile and run the example Console App but not any Web Apps which I want to develop. I have tried all sorts over the last few days (Creating web Config, amending appsettings.json etc and nothing seems to work. I thought it might be the version of Win10 but the VS 2019 Prerequisites say that it is supported in Win10 Home. They all report the same issue:
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

[image: Win10 System Form]

Microsoft Edge Version
[image]

Any idea how to resolve it?

Background: I developed several applications (Web and Console) on the previous laptop on Win 7 in VS 2013 without any major problems running IE and now I want to upgrade my laptop and development system. I did install VS 2017 previously on my new laptop but the notes say that VS2019 will run in parallel successfully with it. I feel that I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This was an IIS issue which was resolved by editing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Web.Config
Changed Permissions to allow Web.Config to be changed, then edited it:

```
<system.web>
        <identity impersonate="false"/>
</system.web>
```

The impersonate tag was changed from true to false.
When Visual Studio was started a new Application was created and Authentication changed to Windows Authentication and it worked!